# "it is put back now" - is this correct?

Tags: past-tense

My friend asked me to put the things back where it was and I replied "It is put back now" -- was that correct?

Comment: ... _put the things back where **it** was_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty borderline and wonky, though technically correct, even if it rubs us the wrong way.

Here are some other ways you could phrase it:  "I have put it back", "It has been put back", or "It is replaced".

Answer (score 2):

When someone says that, I interpret it as important to the individual to have things in a certain state and condition.

If they're asking you to specifically "put the things back where <s>it was</s> they were", they're asking for more than you to just return the item, for example to their hand.

To match their level of specificity, "it is put back" is a little blunt. The problem isn't so much that it's wrong or bad, it's just lacking. I'd say something like,

> Everything's back the way it was.

Or, to put them at ease more humorously (because it's also particularly specific),

> Everything's been restored to its original state and condition. [Thanks for letting me use/borrow them.]

So, the problem is its terseness given the specific request.